# LINQ approach to this code

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method right now that loops through a list of business objects (property *Properties*) to test if property `SerialNumber` is a serial number or not.  If I find a serial number, I exit the loop and return true, otherwise I return false.

Code is as follows:

```
  public bool HasSerialNumber()
  {
      if (this.Properties != null && this.Properties.Count > 0)
      {
          foreach (var property in Properties)
          {
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(property.SerialNumber))
                  return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
```

Is there a better LINQ approach to this?

I have the following in mind:

```
return Properties.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SerialNumber)).ToList().Count > 0;
```

Is there a better/faster method for checking for non-empty string?

Comment: Even with your example, you can use `.Count()` instead of `.ToList().Count` to speed things up a bit. `Any()` is the way to go though.

Comment: @callum It gave me a compiler error when I had just .Count() so I had to call ToList().  Unless I was calling it wrong...

Comment: @snow: Strange, it should work. At least this does: `var strs = new[] {"", "lol", null}; Console.WriteLine(strs.Where(s=> string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).Count());`

Comment: @Callum Try returning a bool where Count > 0

Comment: I'm late to the party, but the reason it only works with `.ToList()` is that you're using the `Count` *property*; you should use the `Count()` method (which works on any `IEnumerable<T>`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `Any` instead of checking if the count is greater than zero.

```
return Properties.Any(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SerialNumber))
```

and of course your `Properties.Count > 0` check is redundant.

Comment: +1. Apart from better communicating your intent, the added bonus of using `Any()` is that the underlying list will only be iterated until a property with serial number is found. If you use Count() or ToList(), the complete list must be evaluated, so you lose some performance. Of course, it will  not make a big difference in this case, but still.

Answer (score 9):

Check out [`IEnumerable<T>.Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
public bool HasSerialNumber()
{
    if(this.Properties != null)
        return Properties.Any(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.SerialNumer));
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you'll improve particularly on the performance of `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`, but one pitfall you should be avoiding is the last 2 calls on your query - specifically `ToList()` and `Count()`.

What you are doing there is iterating through every element, converting it to a list (creating a list and adding items in the process, and then iterating through every element on the list to count how many there are - all to check if a single value is empty.

You can use the `Any` method to find if a single element matches certain criteria, like so:

```
return Properties.Any(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SerialNumber));
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
return Properties.Any(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SerialNumber));
```